# How to make multiple charts using highcharts in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, highmaps

This is the relevant code I have:

```
        <script>
            titles = <?php echo json_encode($graphTitles)?>;
            //Loop through the graphs
            for (var graphNO = 0; graphNO < titles.length; graphNO++)
            {                               
               //CREATE NEW CONTAINER
                var container = document.createElement('div'); 
                document.body.appendChild(container);er);

                dates = <?php echo json_encode($recivedDates);?>[titles[graphNO]];
                //I EXTRACT A FEW  MORE ARRAYS THE SAME METHOD
              $(function () 
                {
                  $(container).highcharts({
                      title: {
                          text: titles[graphNO]
                      },
                      xAxis: {
                          categories: dates
                      },
                      series: [{
                          type: 'column',
                          color: 'gold',
                          name: 'Created Issues',
                          data: createdIssues.map(Number)
                      }, 
                       //MORE COLUMN'S AND SOME SPLINES. IT ALL WORKS AS EXPECTED
                  });
                });
            }
        </script>
```

I didn't want to post all the code and just make it messy, what I expected this code to do is:

graphNO has the value of 2, I thought it would loop through twice (which it does), make a container for each loop (which it does), then draw a different graph for each loop it does in the container it just made (but instead it just draws the second graph).

I don't know whats wrong, but any ideas on how to fix this, or any ideas on how to make multiple graphs in a loop would be great help.

Also, this is the first site I'm making so I haven't used javascript, php, or html for more then a day, so sorry if it's really obvious, I couldn't find anything on this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, after a day of trying complex stuff from around the web that didn't work, I ended up thinking what will happen if I remove the function so rather then:

```
             $(function () 
            {
              $(container).highcharts({
                  title: {
```

I just have:

```
              $(container).highcharts({
                  title: {
```

And it all worked perfectly. I don't know why, probably because of how jquery deals with functions, I don't know, I didn't even know what I was using was jquery till an hour ago. But it works if anyone ever wants to do something similar, it works, and feel free to tell me why.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Swikrit Khanal does work, because the function is no longer being over written. When you have it all wrapped in the function, that function will overwrite it's self when it builds the next graph, so you will only be left with the last graph.

Bellow is a way to use a loop and build multiple graphs without removing the function, but rather uniquely name it.

```
for(v=0; v < 5; v++){
 var container = "#container"+v;
 var func_name = "container"+v;
 func_name = function () {
   $(container).highcharts({
   })
 }
func_name()
}
```

Comment: I have follow this and I able to loop but it only print out the last chart only, so any idea to print out all the chart?

Comment: Hey Shi, your issue is the 'func_name' is overwriting itself. Here is an example of multiple graphs, using a highcharts jsfiddle as a base.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7p94xjy/