# How to create multiple highchart and print in HTML page by using for loop?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have below code in order for me to create multiple highchart:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
for(v=1;v<{{ uniindicatorproduct|safe }}+1;v++) {
    var container = "#container"+v;
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var title = { text: '{{ title|safe }}' };
        var xAxis = {categories: {{ t|safe }}, };
        var yAxis = {title: {text: ' '}, };
        var array ={{ y|safe }}
        var series = [],
            i = 0;
        var a = {{ x|safe }}
            lena = a.length
        for (i; i < lena; i++) {
            series.push({
                name: [a[i]],
                data: array[i]
            });
        }
        var json = {};
        .....
        $(container).highcharts(json);
    });
}
</script>
```

I have apply this on my above code [How to make multiple charts using highcharts in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938338/how-to-make-multiple-charts-using-highcharts-in-a-loop), but this code only able to print the last chart, how to make my output that can print out all the highchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons it is not working is that you had not added the code in an anonymous function. Other was that you had added `document.ready` code in for loop of non `document.ready` codes. This makes the code skip the execution until document is ready.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function createElem() {
            for(v=1;v<{{ uniindicatorproduct|safe }}+1;v++) {
                var container = "#container"+v;
                var title = { text: '{{ title|safe }}' };
                var xAxis = {categories: {{ t|safe }}, };
                var yAxis = {title: {text: ' '}, };
                var array ={{ y|safe }}
                var series = [],
                    i = 0;
                var a = {{ x|safe }}
                    lena = a.length
                for (i; i < lena; i++) {
                    series.push({
                        name: [a[i]],
                        data: array[i]
                    });
                }
                var json = {};
                .....
                $(container).highcharts(json);
            }
        }

        //Call the above function once html is ready
        createElem();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks , I get it